# Poisson Process maths question

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm not quite sure how to tackle this question,

The number of customers arriving
to a bank and a supermarket each independently follow a Poisson process with intensity
3 and 5 customers per hour, respectively. What is the probability that the first customer will be
to the bank ?

Any help/guidance is appreciated

Comment: OK, so you are systematically outsourcing your homework on Poisson processes, right? How many more to come?

Comment: do your middleschool homework yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

The time $T_B$ for a customer to arrive at the bank is exponential with mean $1/3$ and the time $T_S$ for one to arrive at the supermarket is an exponential with mean $1/5$, independent from $T_B.$ You just need to compute $P(T_B< T_S).$